# the same result in php or mysql ,which ways is better?

Tags: php, sql

```
    SELECT * FROM tablename.questions 
where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <=date( from_unixtime(question_created))
        order by question_click_count desc
    ;
```

to show 7days data
i can do this in php like this

```
$day =  mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-7,date("Y"));
```

and then query sql

```
select * from 'question'
where question_created < $day and XXXXXXX
```

which way is better way?

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in the database is *much* faster than doing it in PHP.

It's an important consideration if it's happening inside of a loop that repeats 100000 times, but if it's happening once you will not be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is better then PHP inline queries. I describe some reason :

When your table has large amount of data at that time you need to optimize query so you can easily perform optimization on database rather then PHP.

Database layer is always separate from Application layer .

Even you will get some dynamic query & block using database which is more faster then PHP inline queries.

Thanks.